# Почему условия не работает?

Tags: python

Почему bot не угадывает число, если даже цифры совпадают?

```
import random

coin = input("Number:")
bot = 0
bot = random.randint(1, 2)
if coin == bot:
    print("bot угадал")
else:
    print("bot НЕ угадал")
print(bot)
input("\n\nEnter")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
type(coin)
# <class 'str'>
```

## Подробно

Функция `input()` возвращает строку. Предположим в ответ на запрос мы ввели в консоль `1`, тогда значение переменной `coin` будет `"1"` - строка (`str`), первый символ которой `1`

`random.randint(1, 2)` возвращает число, в результате значение переменной `bot` - число (`int`)

Соответственно, когда мы сравниваем две эти переменные (`coin == bot`) то получаем `False` в любом случае. Строка `"1"` никак не равна числу `1`

Вам нужно привести типы переменных друг к другу, например: `coin == str(bot)`, так мы будем сравнивать строку и строку

Comment: А не могли вы немного пояснить?

Comment: @m0d `input("Number:")` возвращает строку (`str`), `random.randint(1, 2)` возвращает число (`int`), дальше вы сравниваете строку и число, что всегда будет False

Comment: Надо изменить типа на число и присвоить другой переменной?
coin = input("Number:")
human = int(coin)
Или не там копаюсь?
Ща помучаюсь))

Comment: @muzqaymoqcom да, но проще `bot` в строку (`bot = str(random.randint(1, 2))`, так не будет варианта когда вы пытаетесь вызвать `int()` на чем-то неподходящем. Отдельную переменную не обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

`input` записывает строку и срaвнивается строка с числом.

Вместо:

```
coin = input("Number:")
```

надо написать:

```
coin = int(input("Number:")
```

Comment: обяснил покоротче